# "la pomme ne tombe pas loin de l'arbre" pour "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree"

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

L'expression

> la pomme ne tombe pas loin de l'arbre

signifiant *tel père, tels fils* et *the apple doesn't fall far from the tree* est-elle courante des nos jours ?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/26169/1109

Comment: Simple précision, le [sens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/la_pomme_ne_tombe_jamais_loin_de_l%E2%80%99arbre) c'est l'_enfant ressemble à ses parents_, alors que _tel père, tel fils_ (au singulier) est une locution synonyme (Wiktionnaire). Merci !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pas tellement. C'est une expression assez rare, qui a un fort accent d'anglicisme.

Les français sont habitués aux expressions imagées donc les gens comprendront, mais *tel père tel fils* est **beaucoup** plus courante.

En bonus, l'expression *les chiens ne font pas des chats* est presque autant utilisée que *tel père tel fils* et signifie la même chose.

Comment: Vu l'époque, je préfèrerais même utiliser la seconde qui n'a pas d'implication de genre et ne devrait donc pas être sujette à une quelconque critique aussi absurde puisse-t-elle être...

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas familier avec ce proverbe, apparemment compris comme étant un équivalent de « Tel père tel fils », auquel, d'ailleurs en anglais je préfère trouver l'équivalent « Like father, like son ».  On en trouve quatre formes ;

- La pomme ne tombe pas loin du pommier.
- La pomme ne tombe jamais loin du pommier.
- La pomme ne tombe jamais loin de l'arbre.
- La pomme ne tombe pas loin de l'arbre.

Sa logique, sans forcer les relations, me semble beaucoup plus générale, et difficile à spécialiser à l'idée dans « Tel père tel fils ». Ce qui vient à l'esprit c'est la situation générale de l'être dans la vie, endroit de naissance, endroit de résidence, ses habitudes, et ce qui est impliqué c'est l'importance de ce « conditionnement » sur le comportement et les opportunités. C'est une maxime qui me rappelle un adage que l'on a pu entendre par le passé,  du moins aux EUA : One is the som of their experiences. La portée de « La pomme ne tombe pas loin du pommier. » ne devrait pas selon cette façon de penser être restreinte à une remarque sur la filiation, même si l'on peut dire qu'elle l'englobe. En anglais ou en français ce genre d'attribution de sens est une erreur, une fausse représentation. Ce qui a peut être été voulu dans cette création était une généralisation du concept de père à celui d'ascendance directe, tout à fait en accord avec la tendance moderne de pallier aux expressions et termes marqués par de nouvelles formes. Mis à part cette possible intention , le point de vue suivant corrobore les [miens](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/1509/la-pomme-ne-tombe-jamais-loin-de-l-arbre/) et va même beaucoup plus loin en cela qu'il dépasse le domaine d'application à l'être humain pour s'étendre à tout ce qui implique un résultat. L'interprétation choisie est « Le produit est toujours près de son origine. ».

Une représentation plus juste de ce que l'on voudrait que signifie ce proverbe, en anglais et en français, aurait été quelque chose comme « Le fruit tient de la graine.<sup>1</sup> ».

<sup>1</sup><sub>idée personnelle</sub>